# Finding missing element in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists `J2` and `J10`. I am trying to find the elements in `J10` which are absent in `J2` but I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
J2=[128, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

J10=[4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 128]

J=[i for i in J10 not in J2]
print(J)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    J=[i for i in J10 not in J2]

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

The expected output is

```
[13]
```

Comment: `J=[i for i in J10 if i not in J2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
J=[i for i in J10 if i not in J2]
```

Or:

```
lst=[]
for i in J10:
    if i not in J2:
        lst.append(i)
#[13]
```

Or

```
set(J10)-(set(J2))
```

Comment: The second doesn't seem simpler than the first.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Chris. i will remove the word simply:)

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job:

```
temp = list(filter(lambda x: x not in J2, J10))
print(temp)
```

Here is why your code fails:

`J10 not in J2` is treated as an expression that checks if J10 (as a whole is in J2). In other words, the `J10 not in J2` will be either True or False and since a boolean is not a storage-like element such as a list, you can not iterate it.
if you want to solve your problem with syntax you were trying, you should use:

```
J=[i for i in J10 if i not in J2]
```

Comment: Explaining what was wrong with the OP's code would improve this answer.

Answer (score 2):

```py
J=[i for i in J10 if i not in J2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(set(J2).symmetric_difference(J10))
```

Comment: Solution 2 will not produce the expected results, as items in `J2` which are not in `J10` would show up in the results. To correct, intersect with `J10`.

Comment: yes, you are right, Removed solution 2!

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because it's parsed as:

```
[i for i in (J10 not in J2)]
```

`J10 not in J2` returns a boolean value that you can't iterate over. You are missing an `if`.

```
[i for i in J10 if i not in J2]
```

Sets may be useful here, though, as the membership check if O(len(J2)) and the outer loop is O(len(J10)), making this a potentially quite expensive approach.

```
>>> set(J10) ^ set(J2) & set(J10)
{13}
```

First we find the set of items that are unique to each set. TO ensure this contains only unique elements from `J10`, we then intersect with `J10`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way..

```
J2=[128, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
J10=[4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 128]
J=list(set(J10).difference(J2))
print(J)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).